# unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-5

Environment: Visual Studio 2013  and Mvc 5

I am upgrading my site from VS 2010 & MVC 3 to VS 2013 & MVC 5. This works just fine in VS 2010 & MVC 3,  where as in the upgrade project (VS 2013 & MVC 5) it is erroring out with the following message.

**Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique. The following validation type was seen more than once: date**

Class

```
public partial class FileTransferFilterCriteria
    {
        public string Fice { get; set; }
        public string SourceEmail { get; set; }
        public string TargetEmail { get; set; }

        public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
```

Meta Data

```
[MetadataType(typeof(FileTransferFilterCriteria.FileTransferFilterCriteriaMetaData))]
    public partial class FileTransferFilterCriteria
    {
        public class FileTransferFilterCriteriaMetaData
        {
            [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
            [Date(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessageConstants.InvalidDate)]
            [UIHint(UiHintEditorTemplateConstants.DateCalendar)]
            [UIHint(UiHintDisplayTemplateConstants.Date)]
            public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
            [Date(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessageConstants.InvalidDate)]
            [UIHint(UiHintEditorTemplateConstants.DateCalendar)]
            [UIHint(UiHintDisplayTemplateConstants.Date)]
            public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

Html

```
<tr>
                    <th>Upload From Date</th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Criteria.FromDate, UiHintEditorTemplateConstants.DateCalendar)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Criteria.FromDate)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Upload To Date</th>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Criteria.ToDate, UiHintEditorTemplateConstants.DateCalendar)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Criteria.ToDate)
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Editor Template

```
@using System.Globalization

@model DateTime?


@Html.TextBox("", 
(Model != null && 
Model.HasValue && 
!Model.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains("1900") &&
!Model.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains("0001") 
? 
Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") 
: 
string.Empty), 
new { @class = "datePicker", maxlength = "12", size = "12" })
```

**What is wrong here?**

Resulting HTML from VS 2010 & MVC 3 project:

```
<tr>
                    <th>Upload From Date</th>
                    <td>



<input class="datePicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="Invalid date specified. Date should be like MM/DD/YYYY." id="Criteria_FromDate" maxlength="12" name="Criteria.FromDate" size="12" type="text" value="" />

                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Criteria.FromDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Upload To Date</th>
                    <td>



<input class="datePicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="Invalid date specified. Date should be like MM/DD/YYYY." id="Criteria_ToDate" maxlength="12" name="Criteria.ToDate" size="12" type="text" value="" />

                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Criteria.ToDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Resulting HTML - VS 2013 and MVC 5, when i take out the date attribute:

```
<tr>
                    <th>Upload From Date</th>
                    <td>


<input class="datePicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Upload From Date must be a date." id="Criteria_FromDate" maxlength="12" name="Criteria.FromDate" size="12" type="text" value="" />

                        <br/><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Criteria.FromDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Upload To Date</th>
                    <td>


<input class="datePicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Upload To Date must be a date." id="Criteria_ToDate" maxlength="12" name="Criteria.ToDate" size="12" type="text" value="" />

                        <br/><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Criteria.ToDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Try removing `[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]`.

Comment: Yep, thats what i found out by mistake... Thanks

Comment: There is still a problem as described below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just spoke too soon, still need help with Chrome Version 31.0.1650.57 m.

Validation is working normal in FF, IE, and Opera

Code to submit:

```
searchFormSubmit: function ($form, currentForm) {
        //close all clue tips
        JSGlobalVars.ClueTipClose();

        if ($form.valid()) {
            var $button = $("#" + FileTransferHome._enum.SubmitButton);
            var $searchResults = $("#" + FileTransferHome._enum.SearchResultsDivId);

            jMessage("Processing request...", $button, true, false);
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: currentForm.action,
                type: currentForm.method,
                data: $form.serialize(),
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    jMessageHide();
                    $searchResults.html(xhr.responseText).addClass(JSGlobalVars.MessageBoxError).fadeIn('slow');
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    jMessageHide();
                    $searchResults.removeClass(JSGlobalVars.MessageBoxError).html(result).fadeIn('slow');
                    location.hash = "SEARCHRESULTS";
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Following files added for validation:

```
<!-- ***** Validate ***** -->
<script src="/Scripts/Core/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Core/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have changed the data type to "string" for both from and to dates and applied date attribute to it. FF, IE, Opera works where as Chrome is still not properly validating it.

Comment: I removed date attribute and then applied regex attribute and chrome worked as well this time.

Looks like Mvc 5 and dataannotations.org are having some kind of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have upgraded MVC3 application to MVC4 application and changed target framework to 4.0. I have no build errors.

But, I got the same error on below line

```html
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CmpnySearchReportCriteria.ReportReturnDueDateFrom)
```

Data annotation attribute was decorated in model as below.

```
[Display(Name = "Due Date From")]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid date (format: MM/DD/YYYY) for From Report / Return Due Date.")]
public DateTime? ReportReturnDueDateFrom { get; set; }
```

I have written custom client side validation rule for date input field like below. Because automatic type checking validation for date was not available in MVC3.

```
public class ModelClientValidationDateRule : ModelClientValidationRule
{
     public ModelClientValidationDateRule(string errorMessage)
     {
           ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
           ValidationType = "date";
      }
}
```

observed that, MVC4 added automatic type checking validation to any DateTime fields. In MVC4, default client validation message is rendered like below.

data-val-date="The field **{PropertyName}** must be a date."

> Because of our custom client side validation rule data-val-date
>   attribute was rendered twice. This is the cause of this error i.e.
>   "Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be
>   unique."

```
<input class="datefield hasDatepicker" **data-val="true" data-val-date="The field UpdateDate must be a date." data-val-date="Please enter a valid date (format: MM/DD/YYYY) for From Date."** id="UpdateDate" name="UpdateDate" type="text" value="">
```

**To Fix this -**

1. Comment data annotation attribute

   `public class PreInvoiceSearchCriteria
   {
       //[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid date 
         //(format: MM/DD/YYYY) for From Date.")]
       public DateTime? RenewDate { get; set; }
   }`
2. If you don’t want default validation message you can update it using JQuery like below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#DateOfInc').attr("data-val-date", "Please enter a valid date   (format: MM/DD/YYYY) for Date of Inc")
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though i took out the date attribute, the validation still happened after picking up the html for above thread. I left the validation code in there.

This prompted me to make another search and found following:
https://github.com/srkirkland/DataAnnotationsExtensions/issues/46

> Comment By: srkirkland towards the middle of the page:
>
> I think MVC4 added automatic type checking validation to any DateTime
>   fields, so basically if your property is of type DateTime, then the
>   [Date] attribute is not necessary (and will error out, like above). If
>   you have a string property you want formatted as a Date, you can still
>   use [Date].
>
> I'll confirm this and update the website/docs to reflect it. I'll also
>   look to see if I can somehow do a check and only add the validation
>   attribute in the proper case (essentially, MVC3 and below if the
>   property is of type DateTime) .

This brings out another point about the calendar control used with editorfor. Per one comment here, in chrome a jquery and chrome calendar controls will show at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in MVC 5. In my model I had:

```
using DataAnnotationsExtensions;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

What I did was remove the default "using DataAnnotationsExtensions;" statement to leave only:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

So far, this has fixed it without disrupting any existing validators including my custom functions.