# VS 2013 MVC 5 Data Annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have included the package in my VS 2013 and Mvc 5 project for the dataannotations. 
http://dataannotationsextensions.org/

When i use the "Date" attribute with DateTime data type then i get into this issues:
[unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133746/unobtrusive-client-validation-rules-must-be-unique/20135479)

I removed the "date" attribute and left the validation message in there. FF, IE and Opera kicked in the validation due to the type of the field as "DateTime". Chrome didnt do any thing.

I then changed the type to "String" and applied "Date" attribute. Again FF, IE and Opera validated it where as Chrome ignored it.

I then removed the "Date" attribute and instead put in regex attribute for date check and this time chrome validated the wrong date properly.

Looks like the data annotations . org attributes have an issue in Mvc 5

Has some one else seen this behavior as i may be doing something wrong? I want to check this as well. The code is in my post here:
[unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133746/unobtrusive-client-validation-rules-must-be-unique/20135479)